# Convert to Seconds

Tags: t-sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, error-reporting

I am creating a report in SSRS where part of my solutions required  me to convert the following result of the query to be calculate in seconds.

What do I use to get the results of this query in Seconds

```
Format(Fields!Created.Value, "HH:mm") >= "18:00" And Format(Fields!Created.Value, "HH:mm") <= "18:59" , DateAdd(dateinterval.Hour, 14, Fields!Created.Value)
```

I already tried Minute but it did not work

Thanks,

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want to get out of this. You're trying to say that if a time is between 6:00 pm and 6:59 pm then add 14 hours to the datetime value. Where do seconds play into this?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do either. If you want to use the Format function or Format property, seconds are **ss** - HH:mm:ss.